# Trying to add ng-app name does not give expected output in Application

Tags: angularjs, html, ng-app

I am trying to add an `ng-app` tag in my sample AngularJS application.

Whenever I try to add a name like this `ng-app="myapplication"`, the web page stops working. It is supposed to print the name entered in entry box after Hello as shown below.
[image]

The sample code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>First App</title>
    <script src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myapplication">
    <h1>Sample AJS</h1>
    <div >
        <p>Enter your Name : <input type="text" ng-model="name"></p>
        <p>Hello <span ng-bind = "name"></span> !</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

If i replace the `ng-app="myapplication"` to `ng-app=""` , it gives expected output.

I tried using `ng-app` with `<div ng-app="myapplication">`  and

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myapplication" >
```

but the webpage is not populating the name entered in text box if giving a name to the `ng-app`

What could be going wrong. Any help is appreciated !

> IDE : WebStorm2016.2 
> OS: Windows 7

**EDIT:**
**app.js**

```
'use strict';

// Declare app level module which depends on views, and components
angular.module('myApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'myApp.view1',
  'myApp.view2',
  'myApp.version'
]).
config(['$locationProvider', '$routeProvider', function($locationProvider, $routeProvider) {
  $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');

  $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/view1'});
}]);
```

Comment: Can you post your javascript? Ng-app refers to the name of your module.

Comment: where is your controller code and other js stuff?

Comment: @hsiung I have edited the question with app.js code

Comment: ng-app should be `ng-app="myApp"` not `ng-app="myapplication"`

Comment: Rakeschand is correct. The name of your module is whatever you give to it as your first argument, in this case 'myApp'. Putting ng-app in the html let's angular know what module you want to use as the main application module.  The way it knows which one you want is by matching up the names, otherwise it won't be able to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reference to myApp module in `<div ng-app="myApp">` is from `angular.module('myApp', [])`. So You gotta use `ng-app="myApp"` instead of  `ng-app="myapplication"` As @hsiung commented-

"The name of your module is whatever you give to it as your first argument, in this case 'myApp'. Putting ng-app in the html let's angular know what module you want to use as the main application module. The way it knows which one you want is by matching up the names, otherwise it won't be able to find it."

More explanation here [ng-app](http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/angularjs/angularjs-ng-app-directive)

Answer (score 1):

Try include your app.js file to the html file

```
<script src="path/to/app.js"></script>
```